# Flex TextArea leading invalid

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

When I set leading to 0 with Verdana (and others to) for a Flex TextArea I get strange results:

fontsize -> space between baselines

```
 8 -> 10  (125%)
10 -> 12  (120%)
12 -> 14  (117%)
14 -> 17  (121%)
16 -> 18  (113%)
18 -> 22  (122%)
20 -> 25  (125%)
25 -> 31  (124%)
```

Shouldn't all of these be the same (should only be 100%)? Or least follow a pattern, because I can't se any. :(

When I set leading to 0, the space between my baselines should be the same as the font size/height. This is not the case here.

How do I know how to get the space between the baseline to be equal to the height of the font?

Comment: Flash/Flex is notoriously bad with text... you might have more control if you move to FP 10 and look into the text layout engine? http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/

Comment: thanks, I saw that Flex 4.0 included the new text engine so I'll be using that now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrated the project to Flex 4.0 (should have said that I was using 3.5) and use lineHeight instead, where I get the expected results. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try line-height?